# Почему при использовании torctl у меня всегда один и тот-же входной узел

Tags: tor

Здравствуйте я использую https://github.com/BlackArch/torctl что бы обходить различные блокировки но при анализе трафика я заметил что у меня всегда один и тот-же входной узел даже после `torctl restart`. Выходной узел всегда изменяеться а почему не меняеться входной?

Comment: Гуглите Tor Guard Node.